# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AggregateError: Issuer.discover() failed. [auth0] [express] [openid-connect]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, openid-connect, auth0

I ran a local instance of this example app : [here](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-express-webapp-sample/tree/master/01-Login) and ran into an error which i currently find no solutions of.

```
[01-Login]$ npm start

> auth0-express-webapp-sample@ start /mnt/ALPHA/Projects/auth0-express-webapp-sample/01-Login
> node server.js

Using 'form_post' for response_mode may cause issues for you logging in over http, see https://github.com/auth0/express-openid-connect/blob/master/FAQ.md
Listening on http://localhost:3000
(node:8779) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AggregateError: Issuer.discover() failed.
    RequestError: write EPROTO 140236193597312:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
    RequestError: write EPROTO 140236193597312:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
    at Function.discover (/mnt/ALPHA/Projects/auth0-express-webapp-sample/01-Login/node_modules/openid-client/lib/issuer.js:265:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8779) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8779) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

By the looks of it i need a promise resolver on an async function in the example

Although i tried this example on different versions of node (stable/latest even 13.x) and had the same problem. Some insight might be helpful! thank you